# Call Rake task multiple times with argument from list

Tags: rake, xargs

I have a list of e-mails in a `.txt` file. I would like to run a Rake task for each of the e-mails in the file, the e-mail being given as an argument.

I was thinking about `xargs bundle exec rake my_task <file.txt`, but Rake doesn't accept arguments like this. How can I go around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with:

```
xargs -I '{}' bundle exec rake my_task['{}'] <file.txt
```